# Cannot save Adobe Illustrations as .pdf files

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator

I use adobe Illustrator creative suite 3.
Now there seems to be a problem.
I can't save my Illustrations In the .pdf format, since this format seems to preserve the graphic quality this Is vitally Important to me.
If I save the Graphic In .jpef /.gif or png there Is some serious loss of quality so I need to find out a way to get this sorted.

when I try to save the graphic as pdf It says "An unknown error has occured"

please can anyone help me out here?

Thank you,

Comment: Hi guys,
Thanks for taking time and answering my question,Thats really why I love sof.

I think I'v found the Issue,I think there's a corrupt font somewhere.because whenever I remove the font and then save as .pdf It works.

any solutions to this? I need the font's for obvious reasons.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried 'printing' to PDF i.e choose 'Print' then from the 'Printer' choice select Adobe PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Is your drawing too complex? I had the same problem once because I had complexity in path and point data, and the resolution was too high.

Answer (score 0):

Can Illustrator save in the format `.svg` (scalable vector graphics)? `.svg` If so this is probably a better alternative. Read more about `.svg` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg).

Comment: yes, I can save It as .svg but do you need an .svg viewer to view the file?
because I tried to save It as an .svg but how can I view the file ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Parastar You should be able to view it with all modern browsers. Illustrator should also be able to open the exported file.